# How can I write execute store procedure when update Entity using jpa Native Query?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

1. Execute store procedure
2. Update A Table

Query is working Sql

```
@Query("UPDATE A SET A.No=(SELECT * FROM f_SP(tn,year,'name','1'))
,A.status=7  WHERE id=:id") 
A saveObject(@Param("year") Integer year, @Param("tn") Long tn,          
@Param("name") String name, @Param("id") Long id);
```

Comment: errm, if you **Spring** `@Query` then you need to specify nativeQuery=true to use a NATIVE query (i.e SQL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to separate out the stored proc query and the update query at repository level like this :

```
@Procedure(procedureName = "f_SP")
Long reconcileEOMAndPIPSP(Long tn, String name, 'name','1');

@Query("UPDATE A SET A.No= :spResult ,A.status=7  WHERE id=:id") 
A saveObject(@Param("spResult") Long spResult, @Param("id") Long id);
```

and wire then together at the calling class.